# ASP.NET Application Pool logs out user permanantely

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have the oddest situation...

On my ASP.NET website when the application pool recycles the user is logged out.  This is fine.  I know this is suppose to happen.  But when the user logs back in and selects any link within the website, they are logged back out immediately.  They consistently get logged out.  I don't know what causes this and I don't know how to fix it.

The odd part is the work-around.  If I log in from a different computer or from the IIS Server itself than the user that is getting logged out can log back in.

Does anyone have any ideas as to what is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the problem.  In the Security settings of the ASP.NET Configuration each user that logs in needed to have one of the roles defined in the "Description" field.  This is very odd to me be but it seemed to do the trick.  Anyone know why this needs to be done?

Answer (score 3):

Standard Forms Authentication in ASP.NET is cookie-based and should not be affected by the session vanishing. But, you're probably relying on something in the session to determine whether or not the user is logged in. If you're using in-process session storage (and it sounds like you are), then your application code might act strangely if you get in a state where the Forms Authentication cookie still exists and is valid but the session information is missing. Instead of going to a different computer, try blowing away your cookies and logging in again, and I would presume that your issue is resolved.

One step is to move to out-of-process session storage (such as the ASP.NET State Server, which is simple to use with a few config changes) or to eliminate session usage entirely (by depending on values stored in cookies, though there are security implications there to consider if these values are not encrypted). Then, take a close look at how your application code handles the condition where a login cookie is set but the session data is invalid.

It's a shot in the dark based on the information provided, but hopefully it puts you or someone else on the right track.

Comment: Thanks for the help... I'm looking into this.  But I have more information.  It's not a different computer or browser that fixes the issue its the user that logs in.  I'm currently looking into to what is different between the users

Comment: The user that is logged in needs to be apart of .NET Authorization Rules.  I don't want to do that.  The users are managed in the database.  I don't want to add them to the config everytime.  What am I doing wrong?